# How to reset WebLogic 12C password if forgotten

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

How i can reset the weblogic Admin password if the password is forgotten. I have tried the below approach to recover the existing encrypted password from boot.properties, but it's throwing:

```
- "weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding"
```

Steps that i tried-

```
export JAVA_HOME=/apps/JDK/jdk1.8.0_221

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
 
cd /apps/user/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/WCC_DOMAIN/bin

./setDomainEnv.sh

cd /apps/user/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/common/bin


from weblogic.security.internal import BootProperties

BootProperties.load("/apps/user/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/WCC_DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties", false)

prop = BootProperties.getBootProperties()

print "username: " + prop.getOneClient()

print "password: " + prop.getTwoClient()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you forget the AdminServer password for your WebLogic domain, you can reset it from the command line using the following process.

```
export MW_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/middleware
export DOMAIN_HOME=$MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/ClassicDomain

Shut down the WebLogic domain.

$ $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopWebLogic.sh

Rename the data folder.

$ mv $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data-old

Set the environment variables.

$ . $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh

Reset the password using the following command. Remember to substitute the appropriate username and password.

$ cd $DOMAIN_HOME/security
$ java weblogic.security.utils.AdminAccount <username> <password> .

Update the "$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties" file with the new username and password. The file format is shown below.

username=<username>
password=<password>

Start the WebLogic domain.

$ $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/startWebLogic.sh
```